# fetch all items in a GCS bucket python while it is still being written

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using python GCS client.

I want to list all blobs that are part of a bucket at the given time, but the system keeps writing new data to this bucket all the time, and a lot faster than I read

Is it possible that my

```
all_blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucket))
```

will run forever?
Does it keep bringing new items?
Does it run on a snapshot and will eventually finish?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use page token to iterate over the pages of the APIs

```
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(max_results=1000)
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
print(blobs.next_page_token)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(page_token=blobs.next_page_token, max_results=1000)
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
```

There is 2 interesting part in this example

- You can set the max_result equal to 1000 (max value) to have largest page to use
- The Next Page Token is the Base64 encoded name of the latest object/version returned, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list)

The documentation also mention that:

- If a blob is create before the Next Page Token (let say in the alphabetically order), you won't list it by iterating over the next pages
- A the opposite, if a blob is create after the Next Page Token you will see it in the further iterations.